# Python causes Casperjs to ignore wait time, DOM element and runs twice in a row

Tags: python, python-2.7, phantomjs, casperjs

CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3, using phantomjs version 1.9.8 along with Python 2.7.6 on OSX 10.10.4 64-bit.

Thanks for stopping by and reading!

I'm using python to launch a casperjs script. The casperjs script works perfectly when launched in bash with *casperjs myscript.js* but it shows errors in its behaviour when launched with the following python code:

```
import os
import subprocess
args = ['/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/casperjs', '/Users/john/Documents/myjstests/myscript.js'] 
subprocess.call(args) 


APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.sys.argv[0])


CASPER = '/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/casperjs'
SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'myscript.js')

params = CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT 

print subprocess.call(params, shell = True)
```

Below is an abridged version of my casperjs script

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
});

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36');


casper.start('http://www.allforthewatch.bigcartel.com/').viewport(1920, 1080); //The store

casper.wait(5000, function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    casper.capture('store1.png');

 });

casper.then(function(){
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="home"]/div/section[2]/ul/li/a/img')); 
});


casper.wait(5000, function(){
    casper.capture('store2.png');
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="product"]/div/section[1]/section[2]/form/button'));
});

casper.wait(5000, function(){
    casper.capture('store3.png');
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.click(x('//*[@id="cart"]/div/section/form/button')); 
});

casper.wait(5000, function(){
    casper.capture('store4.png');
});

casper.then(function(){
    casper.sendKeys(x('//*[@id="buyer_first_name"]'), 'John');
});

casper.wait(5000, function(){
    casper.capture('store5.png');
});



casper.run();
```

So far there are three notable errors in the script's behaviour when launched with python:

1-The captures show missing images.

2-Elements are not found, even if they are in fact present. This is confirmed by the following error message in the terminal

```
Johns-MacBook-Pro:myjstests john$ python mypythontest.py
All For The Watch — Home
CasperError: Cannot get informations from xpath selector: //*[@id="buyer_first_name"]: element not found.
  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/modules/casper.js:1058 in getElementInfo
  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/modules/casper.js:1589
  /Users/vegaforte/Documents/myjstests/myscript.js:43
  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/modules/casper.js:1553 in runStep
  /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep
```

3-The script runs twice in a row. This is most likely due to *myscript.js* being passed in *args* as well as at the end through *params*.

Noted error #1 seems to be due to the script being "rushed" through its steps. I think that the 5000 ms waits are being ignored. This is further supported when I look at the variations between captures. Following will be a set of "A" captures
taken by launching in bash with *casperjs myscript.js* and then a set of "B" captures taken when the script is launched in bash with *python* *mypythontest.py*.

Notice that in set "B" images 3B and 4B are the same. It's as if it's stuck at that step. After this point in the script (when launched with python) the error message appears in the console and it stops executing, thus no image 5B.

I looked into possible issues with the way that casperjs is called with subprocess but so far, for the use of casperjs with python, this seems to be the correct use.

At this point I should mention that I have used the same python code with another casperjs script and there are no problems, except that it does run twice in a row as well.

What am I missing that is causing these issues? If you need further clarifications please let me know.

Thank you for your time!

Set "A"
    [image: 1A]
    [image: 2A]
    [image: 3A]
    [image: 4A]
    [image: 5A]

Set "B"
    [image: 1B]
    [image: 2B]
    [image: 3B]
    [image: 4B]

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you for the suggestion :) In this case the code I posted is the minimal, complete code to reproduce the issues I am describing. I appreciate that you pointed out this best practice.

Comment: I haven't read the huge wall of text and images (and I doubt if anyone will), but I seriously doubt an example with ten fat image assets is **minimal**.

Comment: Not making the effort to reduce the problem only has one result: no one will read the question, and hence no answer. It's not in your best interest.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I understand your pov. Casperjs has a very cool feature that allows you to capture web pages/screens to "see" what the headless browser is doing. In the context of my  issues, the captures are essential to emphasize the difference between the correct and incorrect behaviour of the casperjs script.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate... Good luck.

Comment: Could it be that `casperjs` in shell and `/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/casperjs` in python are actually different CasperJS binaries?

Comment: @Vaviloff Hello again! Very happy to hear from you :) That is a very good question. I'll look into it and follow up here.

Comment: Glad I could help, that was the only logical explanation to why would the same script lead to different results.

Comment: @Vaviloff You sir, are magic! That was exactly the problem! Casperjs in shell is using `/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/bin/casperjs`. That is also what I was supposed to use in the python code. Now it works perfectly :) I am very grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This solution was suggested by @Vaviloff I am very grateful for his help :)

The main cause of the problems was that the binaries used by shell and python were
different.

This was the original python code

```
import os
import subprocess
args = ['/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/casperjs', '/Users/john/Documents/myjstests/myscript.js'] 
subprocess.call(args) 


APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.sys.argv[0])


CASPER = '/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/libexec/bin/casperjs'
SCRIPT = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'myscript.js')

params = CASPER + ' ' + SCRIPT 

print subprocess.call(params, shell = True)
```

All that needed to be changed in the python code was `args` and `CASPER` with the following
 `/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta3/bin/casperjs`

With this modification the entire casperjs works flawlessly. All wait times are observed and all DOM elements are found.

The last problem I had was that the script ran twice. A quick and dirty solution I came up with was to remove `/Users/john/Documents/myjstests/myscript.js`from `args`.

I hope this helps out someone with similar issues ;)